# The bearing angle between two vectors?

Tags: math-mode, vector

What is the best way of showing the angle between two vectors defined by start and end points?

E.g., Vector 1 points from point A to point B. Vector 2 points from point C to point D.

I have tried:

```
$\angle (\vec{AB}, \vec{CD})$
```

But it is ugly.

In addition, the abovehead arrowhead is not long enough to cap the long expression. How may I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `\overrightarrow{}` instead of `\vec{}`:

```
$\angle (\overrightarrow{AB}, \overrightarrow{CD})$
```

It will have the following result:

[image: overrightarrow]

Answer (score 2):

```
$ \alpha= \widehat{(\overrightarrow{B_1 }, \overrightarrow{B_2 })} $
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use bold symbols for vectors, like that

```
$\mathbf{a} = \vec{AB}$
$\mathbf{b} = \vec{CD}$

$\alpha = \angle (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$
```